# Deadlocks - locking and waiting for the same index

Tags: sql-server, deadlock

I've got a deadlock occurring in an SQL Server application. I've run SQL Profiler and pulled up a "deadlock graph", and this seems to be telling me that both processes are holding and waiting for a lock on the same primary key index.

The deadlock is being caused by an update to the table, there are multiple threads running and both processes are running the same update stored procedure (although with different parameters). This is fine as the stored proc only increments counters, so previous data state doesn't matter.

i.e. UPDATE xxx SET yyy = yyy + zzz WHERE aaa = @aaa

1. Why are both processes requesting a U lock when they both already hold an X lock, surely they could both perform the update with the X lock?
2. How have both processes got a X lock at the same time?
3. How do I go about fixing this? :-)

Thanks for the help.

[image]

edit: Additional info

The exact procedure is:

```
CREATE PROC spuPlayerStats
    @PlayerId int,
    @HandsPlayed int
AS
BEGIN
        UPDATE Player  
        SET
            HandsPlayed = HandsPlayed + @HandsPlayed
        WHERE
            PlayerId = @PlayerId
END
GO
```

The index is just an int primary clustered index.

Comment: What other statements are in the stored procedure? Deadlocks are not usually caused by single statements conflicting with each other (at least when the statements are this simple and atomic), but usually because there are other statements in each transaction and some of these resources might be affected by those (and/or by order). Can you provide more detail about the rest of the procedure, the indexes and structure of xxx, and the value(s) of @aaa that cause the deadlock? The graph is pretty, but there really isn't any useful information to us, since we can't chase object_ids etc.

Comment: Added additional info at the bottom.

Comment: How about table structure, data types, and are there are other stored procedures being called at the time (e.g. is the call to spuPlayerStats part of a larger transaction)? How many rows in the table? Is the PK clustered? If not, what is the clustered index? What are the values of @aaa that cause this?

Comment: @Will - I'm sure someone else like Aaron can provide better info, but bear in mind these are **ROW LEVEL** locks, not table-level locks.  The actual issue is likely that one of the updates is reading rows that the other is writing and vice versa.  One easy solution would be to add a `TABLOCK` hint to your `UPDATE`

Comment: @JNK right, exactly why I was asking what values of @ PlayerId are supplied when this happens. But if this is all there is, one of the calls to the proc should win, and the other one waits. Hence I think there is a little more to it - I don't recall ever being able to reproduce a deadlock with statements this simple.

Comment: @Aaron - I have seen it before, and I think it would happen with overlapping ranges on the range scan for the `PlayerID` filter.  Still seems like a corner case though.

Comment: I've tried "WITH (ROWLOCK)" and received the same result. Any suggestions as to how I go about getting the parameter values that were passed to the deadlocked stored procedures?

Comment: In addition to deadlock events you'll also need to trace the actual procedure calls (e.g. SP:Completed) with a filter (TextData LIKE '%spuPlayerStats%'). The TextData will contain the actual statement (e.g. '`EXEC spuPlayerStats 1,1`').

Comment: @Will - Try `WITH (TABLOCK)`, ROWLOCK won't solve this.

Comment: @Aaron That doesn't help me identify which were the deadlocked procs. If I've got 10 instances of the same proc, I can't work out how to tell which the deadlocked ones were.

Comment: @JNK I've tried TABLOCK, still deadlocking :(

Comment: @will - then there's something else happening you're not telling us about.  Are you sure these are the only procs running on the server?

Comment: @JNK There are other procs, but these are the ones implicated in the deadlock according to the XML from the deadlock diagram. There is another proc implicated in the deadlock sometimes - an insert on another table with a FK relationship to the PK of the problem index, but this appears less frequently.

Comment: Ok, well I've tried stripping out the insert into the related table and the deadlocks no longer occur. So I'm guessing that's more involved that I first though it was. That's just a simple insert query, no sub-queries. I'll pry further.

Comment: I might have done something wrong before - TABLOCK appears to be working now. Although my current changes are to improve performance, and that's shaved about 33% off the speed, so I don't think that's the solution I'm after. :-(

Comment: @Will I wasn't expecting it to identify it for you 100% - in fact that's a limitation in current versions of Profiler/SS-trace, where you can't capture a deadlock *and* the event that caused it (TextData is `NULL` for those events). I just thought it might help narrow it down.

Comment: With the TABLOCK removed and the INSERT procedure removed the problem procedure is *almost* the only proc running on the database and the deadlocks are still occurring.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you post the actual deadlock XML. The graphical representation is not always accurate, see [The puzzle of U locks in deadlock graph](http://rusanu.com/2010/05/12/the-puzzle-of-u-locks-in-deadlock-graphs/)s. Deadlocks can happen even on deceptively simple statements on well tuned queries, due to order of applying the updates, see [Read/Write deadlock](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/16/readwrite-deadlock/). And deadocks can happen even on systems that apparently are 100% safe, like the one you originally described in the post (one row update in a clustered index w/o secondary index updates, on different keys) due to hash collisions, see [%%lockres%% collision probability magic marker: 16,777,215](http://rusanu.com/2009/05/29/lockres-collision-probability-magic-marker-16777215/).

Now I don't expect your case to be an esoteric one, in your situation what it appears to be is simply lack of information about what actually happens. Please post the *exact* schema definition of your data (all tables, all indexes), the exact operations that occur in each transaction involved, and the actual deadlock XML, not the graphical rendering.

Comment: I'm unable to post the full DB schema I'm afraid, although I agree, I think there is something going on that I don't think is going on (if you see what I mean). Your Read/Write deadlock link looks interesting. I wonder if I might be able to unearth something using that information. I did try pasting in the XML but the website didn't like the formatting.

Comment: some users post attachements to SO trough services like pastebin.com or similar

Answer (score 1):

TRY:

```
SELECT @updateValue = HandsPlayed + @HandsPLayed FROM Player WHERE PlayerId = @PlayerId

UPDATE Player  
    SET
        HandsPlayed = updateValue 
    WHERE
        PlayerId = @PlayerId
```